# Layout Not updating when calling setOrientation in Android

Tags: android, layout

I switch a fragment from one view to the next and then I toggle the orientation. The view does not update to the new Orientation.

```
fm.beginTransaction()
    .remove(mCallBellsFragment)
    .commit();

fm.executePendingTransactions();

fm.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.bed_mode_plan_of_care_fragment_container, mCallBellsFragment)
        .commit();

mCallBellsFragment.toggleOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
```

...

```
public void toggleOrientation(int requestedOrientation) {
    Log.d("AFL", "Current Orientation: " + (LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL == requestedOrientation ? "Horizontal" : "VERTICAL"));
    mCallButtonLayout.setOrientation(requestedOrientation);
    Log.d("AFL", "Set Orientation: " + (mCallButtonLayout.getOrientation() == LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL ? "HORIZONTAL" : "VERTICAL"));
}
```

Logs:

D/AFL: Current Orientation: Horizontal

D/AFL: Set Orientation: HORIZONTAL

However the Orientation remains Vertical on screen.

Answer (score 0):

They Layout needs to be re-drawn to be displayed differently.

Try to call invalidate() after the orientation is reset.

```
mCallButtonLayout.invalidate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the `invalidate()` method as suggested by @Eric Liu, but first try to get focus on said view by calling `requestFocus()`.

If this doesn't work. Try to `invalidate()` the root view of your layout.
Also, this may help, run everything on UI thread by using:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        //Call methods here 
    } 
});
```